# actual time: more than none -- I don't understnad what that means

Tags: comprehension

Source: [JavaScript For Cats](http://file:///C:/Users/cookie_moster/Desktop/JavaScript%20For%20Cats/JavaScript%20for%20Cats.htm)

Example:

> JavaScript started as a way to make web pages more interactive. Nowadays JavaScript runs in more places than just web browsers — it runs on web servers, phones and even robots! This page will teach you some JavaScript basics so that you can get up and running in no time*.
> * Actual time: **more than none**. Probably an hour or two. Also since you are a cat you are less likely to run and more likely to lay around in the sun

I don't really understand what he means by *more than none* in the context of that paragraph.

Comment: "You can get up and running **in no time**" --- Note: "Actual time (until you're up and running) is going to be **more than zero**". I'm not sure why the author(s) chose **none** to indicate "in no time".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to

> How much time did it take?
>   Did it take long?

if it was done quickly, is

> **None**.

It is an AmE colloquialism, without additional comment.

So the authors are saying you will learn Javascript very quickly

> in **no time**

but literally **no time** would mean 0(zero) minutes, which would not be possible, even as a **cat**.
It may also be a **tongue-in-cheek** disclaimer to prevent **false advertising** claims.

Comment: But why did the author use "More than none" ?

Comment: Because the time it will take is >0(zero). He could have easily have said **a few minutes**, **a couple of hours**. To say "Actual time:" in that way sets it up more as a joke. He then plays a pun between **up and running** (an idiom) and physical **running** as a cat.

Comment: Yeah, I took a little time to understand the context. I got the Idea now. +1 for the answer.

Comment: You kind of need to understand the **geeky-techy** humour side of it. First clue should have been: Javascript **For Cats** (!), everyone knows **cats don't like coffee**...